# Чем инициализируется функция Math.random?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Чем инициализируется функция **Math.random()** и можно ли задавать свой инициализатор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Реализация сама выбирает начальное зерно для алгоритма генерации
>   случайных чисел; оно не может быть выбрано или сброшено пользователем.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Если вам нужна такая функциональность, то её придётся реализовывать самостоятельно или использовать готовое решение, например, [это](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom).